# Extract Month from a YYYYMM column in R

Tags: r

I have tried to extract it but the methods seem to only work for YYYY-MM. I have data in terms of a date (YYYYMM) and am trying to get in terms of just the month, such as: Month

Ultimately, I would like it to look like this:

```
ID    Date         Month
1     200402       2
2     200603       3
3     200707       7
```

I am doing this in hopes of plotting monthly mean values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do it using:

```
library(stringr)
str_sub(df$Date,-2,-1)
```

Or using;

```
df['Date'].str[-2:]
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Assuing your `Date` column be numeric, you could just use the modulus:

```
df$Month <- df$Date %% 100
df

  ID   Date Month
1  1 200402     2
2  2 200603     3
3  3 200707     7
```

**Data:**

```
df <- data.frame(ID=c(1,2,3), Date=c(200402, 200603, 200707))
```

To make the above work when `Date` be character, just cast it to numeric first.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract last two characters of `Date` Column.

```
sub('.*(..)$', '\\1', df$Date)
#Or without capture groups suggested by @Tim Biegeleisen
#sub("^.*(?=..$)", "", df$Date, perl = TRUE)
#[1] "02" "03" "07"
```

However, ideally you should avoid parsing information from date-time using regex. Convert it to date and then extract the month.

```
format(as.Date(paste(df$Date, '01'), "%Y%m%d"), '%m')
#Or with zoo::yearmon
#format(zoo::as.yearmon(as.character(df$Date), "%Y%m"), '%m')
```

Comment: I prefer: `sub("^.*(?=..$)", "", df$Date)`, as it avoids the capture group.

Comment: Thanks @TimBiegeleisen . Is there a particular down-side of capture groups ?

Comment: Yes, there is.  Capture groups require the engine to use more storage than a regex which doesn't need/use them.  It's a minor point, but one worth making.